# Redirect Url on Apache Server

Tags: redirect, rewrite, apache2

i have this url:

https://pouv.com/presentation/vues/restreint/gestionnaire/****

i want to redirect to:

https://pouv.com/bo/

I do this on my .conf:

```
  ## Rewrite rules
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule https://pouv.com/presentation/vues/restreint/gestionnaire/$ https://pouv.fr/bo/ [R=301,L]
```

the redirection is not done, why ?

Comment: Why not just use a redirect directive?  Here's an explanation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache

Comment: What do the logs tell you?